# Group contact query throws error in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have written below query and it's perfectly running in Mysql workbench. But when I'm running it from php, it's throwing the error. Any help would be appreciated.

**QUERY:**

```
$sql=SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('max(CASE WHEN date = "',date,'" THEN Market_cap end) AS "',date,'"'))
INTO @sql
FROM company_name
JOIN master on company_name.id=master.company_id
where date between '2018-01-01' and '2018-01-02';

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT name,symbol,',@sql,'FROM company_name join master on company_name.id=master.company_id where date between ''2018-01-01'' and ''2018-01-02''GROUP BY name,symbol');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

$res=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if (!$res) {
    echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($conn));
}
```

Error thrown shown in image:
[image: error snapshot]

Also I have to add my output using above query:
[image: output snapshot]

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '',date,'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$sql="SET @sql = NULL;SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('max(CASE WHEN date = '".$date."' THEN Market_cap end) AS '".$date."'))INTO @sql FROM company_name join master on company_name.id=master.company_id where date between '2018-01-01' and '2018-01-02';SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT name,symbol,',@sql,'FROM company_name join master on company_name.id=master.company_id where date between ''2018-01-01'' and ''2018-01-02''GROUP BY name,symbol');PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;EXECUTE stmt;DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt";
$res= mysqli_query($conn,$sql);if (!$res) {echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error({$conn}));
```

> Note: I was not sure why have you used `"',date,'"` in your query, so
>   replaced it with `'".$date."'`. Make sure to use it as you needed.

Comment: it throws the below error Error description: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('max(CASE WHEN date = '' THEN Market_cap end' at line 1 
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in E:\xampp\htdocs\talend\get_table.php:44 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown

Comment: First tell me what is `"',date,'"`? Is this a PHP variable that you are using?

Comment: date is our column name comes from company_name table